# Laravel - Redirección de usuario tras registrarse

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy tratando de redefinir la redirección de usuario tras el momento en que éste acaba de registrarse.

Por defecto, en un proyecto de Laravel, dentro del `./app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php`, existe esta propiedad con un determinado valor:

**RegisterController.php** (inicialmente)

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que la redirección se haga a la vista de `./resources/views/users/index.php`.

Para ello:

- he creado la carpeta `./resources/views/users`.
- he movido la vista de `./resources/views/home.blade.php` a la carpeta creada y he renombrado el archivo a `index.blade.php`.
- he modificado la ruta referida a '/home' para que quede dirigida a la nueva vista modificada. En la ruta, se tiene en cuenta que se facilita el dato de "username" del usuario que inició sesión.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/users/{username?}', 'API\UserController@index')
    ->name('user_pnl_index');
```

Entonces, con los nuevos parámetros definidos, solamente, me quedaba redefinir la propiedad de `$redirectTo` del `RegisterController.php`, incluyendo el dato de "username" (campo de la tabla de "users" para almacenar el dato de nombre de usuario) del usuario que está autenticado en la ruta de redirección:

**RegisterController.php** (tras modificarlo)

```
protected $redirectTo = '/users/' . Auth::user()->username;
```

Pero, cuando habilito esta línea, supongo que a través de alguno de los verificadores de código que tengo habilitados en el editor, me muestra un mensaje de ERROR que dice:

`Constant expression contains invalid operations`

Comentar que en la cabecera del archivo de RegisterController.php, tengo estos imports:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
```

Entonces, ¿cómo puedo resolver el error de código para poder establecer la ruta deseada como nuevo valor para la propiedad de redirección?

Comment: Para futuras publicaciones, [evita usar etiquetas en los títulos de tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: De acuerdo,  ... trataré de acordarme de lo que me comentas @Jheyman Mejia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lee cuidadosamente lo siguiente:

> Las variables miembros de una clase se llaman propiedades. También las
>   puedes ver referenciadas con otros términos como "atributos" o
>   "campos", para propósito de este ejemplo, usaré "propiedades". Las
>   propiedades son definidas usando alguna de las palabras clave como
>   `public`, `protected` ó `private`, seguida de una declaración normal
>   de variable, esta declaración puede incluir una inicialización de
>   variable, pero esta inicialización debe de ser un valor **constante**,
>   esto es, que debe de ser capaz de ser **evaluado en tiempo de
>   compilación** y **no debe de depender de información en tiempo de
>   ejecución** para que pueda ser evaluada.

Una vez teniendo en mente esto, lo que deberías de hacer es reemplazar la propiedad de clase con un método que te devuelva la ruta:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return route('user_pnl_index', ['username' => auth()->user()->username]);
}
```

El problema de tu caso era que no estabas usando un valor constante en tu declaración de propiedad de la clase...